# hmac hash mismatch in PHP and Go

Tags: php, go, sha256, hmac

I am trying to connect to an API that uses an outdated hmac hash authentication mechanism for the API's.

For an instance:

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $api_sec);
```

vs the one generated in Go:

```
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(authSecret))
h.Write([]byte(stringToSign))
signature := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
```

When I use the same `stringToSign($string_to_sign)` and same `authSecret($api_sec)` the signature generated with Go results as an invalid  signature for the API. But if I create the same with the PHP function it works fine. I am a bit lost as to where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be an issue with your input data.

Using the below PHP:

```
echo hash_hmac('sha256', 'data', 'key');
```

And the below Go:

```
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("key"))
h.Write([]byte("data"))
signature := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
fmt.Println(signature)
```

I get the same result of `5031fe3d989c6d1537a013fa6e739da23463fdaec3b70137d828e36ace221bd0`

Comment: yes this does work, but do you think that strings with "\n" has any different implication? For an instance I am looking at something like that has "POST\n/path/to/route\nsom=strings" because soon as I have a string with \n character the go hash and php hash doesn't match

Comment: Recall that, in PHP, `"\n"` will produce an actual new line character, where as `'\n'` will produce the symbol `\ ` followed by the symbol `n` e.g. literally the string `\n`.  This will cause a difference in your hashes.  If you want them both to interpret `\n` as a new line, use `"\n"` in both.  If you want neither of them to interpret the `\n` as a new line, and as a literal string, use `'\n'` in PHP and `\`\n\`` in Go.

Comment: Finally was able to pin down, the query param order was messed up causing the diff. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.